# List of URI to a Gridview

Tags: java, android, gridview

I'm developing an application that selects a list of images from the gallery  and should display the images before sending to the server, which is already running using retrofit.

This select return a list in `List<URI>` , 
just like in the cod below:

```
Button uploadBtn = findViewById(R.id.btn_button);
uploadBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,true);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Escolha a imagem"),PICK_IMAGE);
        }

    });

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){

        ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
        ArrayList<Uri> fileUris = new ArrayList<>();

        if (clipData == null){
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            fileUris.add(uri);
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                Uri uri = item.getUri();
                fileUris.add(uri);
            }
        }
        uploadAlbum(fileUris);
    }
```

I would like to know if I can use this list to populate a gridview and how can I do it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes you can. Simply create a `GridPane`, load `ImageView`s from the `URI`s, and put those `ImageView`s into the cells of the `GridPane`.

Comment: I didnt find any information about `GridPane` on Android, can you explain more?

Comment: Sorry, I was assuming JavaFX. Which Graphical API are you using? Here's a link if you want to try [JavaFX on android](https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/web_development/9781784398026/4)

Comment: I found one solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found one solution, is parsing **URI** to **BITMAP** with this codes:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){

        ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
        fileUris = new ArrayList<>();
        images = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
            ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
            Uri uri = item.getUri();
            fileUris.add(uri);
            try {
                images.add(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri));
                gridView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, images));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My custom GridviewAdapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> imagens;

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Bitmap> images) {
        mContext = c;
        this.imagens = images;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return imagens.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        }
        else
        {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        imageView.setImageBitmap(images.get(position));
        return imageView;
    }


}
```